# Is this possible make button or link inside workflow form?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Am using `alfresco community edition-5.1.x`, created custom `workflow` in `workflow` form i need to create button or link is this possible? by default activiti `eclipse` not available button or link please help me out?

Comment: All your transitions from particular tasks results into buttons. For instance if you have two possible transitions "approve" and "reject" alfresco will generate two buttons for those transitions in form.

Comment: please provide some code it will help to understand the problem

Comment: Please explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: I have create workflow using activiti in workflow form inside i need to use button filed or link href link

Comment: if you want to add as a control like textbox / date control, then you need to create your own control in share.

Comment: You can refer the below place to refer the existing controls from Alfresco Share (<Alfresco_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\controls